# Rails Nginx: multiple applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, puma

I have two nginx configs for applications:

1) Rails application

```
upstream app {
  server unix:/home/deploy/railsapp/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.example.com;

  root /home/deploy/railsapp/current/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

2) Static html/js application

```
server {
  listen 81;
  server_name  client.example.com;
  root /home/deploy/clientapp;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
   # proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
}
```

The problem is both addresses `api.example.com` and `api.example.com` open the same application (for `api.example.com`)

Comment: @PeterS It's just an example without original addresses. Both addresses are subdomains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some basic tutorial on nginx config; https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-nginx-web-server-on-a-virtual-private-server. You should use a proxy with rails applications **not** with static html application.

```
server {
  listen 80; #should also be 80
  server_name  client.example.com;

  root /home/deploy/clientapp;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
}
```

To test the configuration you can perform `nginx -t` and should reload using `nginx -s reload` to use the new configuration? As stated before this problem has nothing to do with rails, it is just nginx configuration.

The `server_name` is leading on which website is returned on a request, if there is no `default_server` it will return the last website loaded into nginx configuration.

Comment: I tried to listen the same port (80). In this case both addresses open application `/home/deploy/clientapp` which should be only on the `client.example.com`

Comment: @PavelBabin that's because the proxy has nothing to do in your static website configuration! Do you have both configuration linked in de sites-enabled directory?

It should always be port 80, because that's where web application run at.

Comment: I have two separate config files for backend and client. I removed proxy settings from client config and result is the same

Comment: Are both config files linked in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. If you did you reload the configuration `nginx -s reload` or does it have errors `nginx -t`?

Comment: 1) both configs are in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. 2) yes, i'm reloading nginx like `sudo service nginx restart`. 3) no, there is no errors and syntax is ok

Comment: Are there any typos in the `server_name`? And are you using port 80 for both applications already?

Comment: no typos and port 80 for both applications. DNS for both subdomain addresses (api.example.com and client.example.com) is set for one address. Could it be the problem?

Comment: It should be that way if your running both applications on the same server.